# How to use Firebase admin.auth().verifyIdToken in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, token

I am using Firebase admin sdk in nodejs and trying to verfity token as below:

`admin.auth().verifyIdToken(sometoken)` method.

Are "ID Token" and "Registration Tokens" the same thing?

Comment: no they are different

Comment: ID tokens are obtained after user authentication. You can get them via `user.getIdToken()` calls on the client. You would send them to your server to verify the user session.